# Makefile wildcard rules for multiple file extensions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a number of assembly and C source files in a directory. I have mentioned a list of files to be compiled as `C_OBJFILES` and `ASM_OBJFILES`. I have added the rules as

```
%.o: %.S
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

for generating the object files. Some of the assembly files has .s extension. Some has .S and remaining .asm. Is there a way to specify these different extensions in a single rule instead of separate %.o:%.asm and %.o:%.s?

Although it can be solved by a simple prename before make, I would like to explore the options with Makefile. Below is the complete Makefile I have written.

```
ASM_OBJLIST:=startup.o vectors.o lowlevel.o
C_OBJLIST:=test.o
LD_SCRIPT:=test.ld

CROSS_COMPILE:=arm-none-eabi-
AS:=$(CROSS_COMPILE)as
CC:=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD:=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
OBJCOPY:=$(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy

CFLAGS:= -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g
ASFLAGS:= -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g

BIN_TARGET:=test.bin

$(BIN_TARGET): $(C_OBJLIST) $(ASM_OBJLIST)
    $(LD) -T $(LD_SCRIPT) -o $@.elf $^
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $@.elf $@

%.o: %.S
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.elf *.bin
```

If handling multiple extensions in a single rule is possible, I can just use gcc for all source files instead of bothering to use as at all. (I guess)

Comment: Build works fine for all .S and .c files

Comment: GNU Make already knows how to handle `.s` and `.S` (and of course `.c`) files, so none of your rules are really necessary.  You will need one for `.asm` though.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: @tripleee, Thank you. I new about C files (making without a makefile), but didn't knew about the remaining file types. But what if I need different rules for assembly and C files? May be like running a different program on assembly source before assembling them with gcc? Or explicitly run as instead off gcc driver?

Comment: Then overriding the built-in rule makes sense, of course.  I don't have an answer to your actual question about doing it for multiple file extensions in one go, unfortunately.

Comment: @tripleee, for the second scenario (explicitly run as instead off gcc driver), the implicit rule would work. The link you have given says precise recipe is ‘$(AS) $(ASFLAGS)’. So that part is covered. Sorry I didn't read it well earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use static patterns and split the objects into two sets, there are a number of other improvements too

- Make already has defaults for things like `AS` and `CC`, use them.
- You're already using `ASFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` correctly (except for `-c`, see below), use the same pattern for other flags too
- You missed a chance to express the bin->elf dependency
- You can recycle the built-in recipes even if you need to redefine the rules (`LINK.o`, `COMPILE.c` which already has the `-c` flag), although the `.c` rule is currently superfluous as it's exactly the same as the built-in one.
- clean should be `PHONY`
- **Never** delete stuff with `*`, explicitly delete only the files you are responsible for.

I'd just use GCC to link but if you need to link with `LD` then you'll need to change the recipe.

---

```
ASM_OBJLIST := startup.o
S_OBLIST    := vectors.o lowlevel.o
C_OBJLIST   := test.o
LD_SCRIPT   := test.ld

CROSS_COMPILE := arm-none-eabi-

AS      := $(CROSS_COMPILE)$(AS)
CC      := $(CROSS_COMPILE)$(CC)
OBJCOPY := $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy

CFLAGS   := -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g
ASFLAGS  := -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g
LDFLAGS  := -Wl,-T $(LD_SCRIPT)
OBJFLAGS := -O binary 

BIN_TARGET := test.bin

$(BIN_TARGET): $(BIN_TARGET).elf
    $(OBJCOPY) $(OBJFLAGS) $< $@

$(BIN_TARGET).elf: $(C_OBJLIST) $(ASM_OBJLIST)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(ASM_OBJLIST): %.o: %.asm
$(S_OBJLIST): %.o: %.S
$(ASM_OBJLIST) $(S_OBJLIST):
    $(COMPILE.S) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(C_OBJLIST) $(ASM_OBJLIST) $(BIN_TARGET).elf $(BIN_TARGET)
```

Comment: This syntax has always confused me while going through Makefiles in Android source
$(ASM_OBJLIST): %.o: %.asm

$(S_OBJLIST): %.o: %.S

$(ASM_OBJLIST) $(S_OBJLIST):

Can you please point to a documentation/additional details about the X : Y : Z statements?

Comment: @subin [Static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html).